# Flattening scala.immutable.Seq with -Yno-predef flag

Tags: scala, implicit, predef

I am using custom `Predef` with `-Yno-predef` flag. It is basically a copy of [SlamData's one](https://github.com/slamdata/slamdata-predef/blob/master/src/main/scala/slamdata/Predef.scala).

When I try to flatten nested immutable `Seq`s collections I receive error:

```
No implicit view available from my.Predef.Seq[String] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[String].
```

If I put `import scala.Predef._` it will compile again. I tried to investigate `scala.Predef` and `scala` package object but when I tried to copy `TraversableOnce`'s, `Traversable`'s or `Seq`'s definitions it didn't help.

Do someone know which part of vanilla predef is responsible for generating this implicit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `Predef.$conforms`.

A way to figure it out is to run `scala -Xprint:typer -e 'Seq(Seq(1)).flatten'` on the command line.
It'll print the entire syntax tree, with all implicits resolved.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I've found out that what I was missing was:

```
type <:<[-From, +To] = scala.Predef.<:<[From, To]
implicit def $conforms[A]: A <:< A = scala.Predef.$conforms[A]
```

Apparently it is required for implicit evidence used inside all those type class derivation inside companion objects.